# I want to split date by month and year in single layout

Tags: java, performance

I am want to split the date like hour and minute. I have used this code in my Android app:

```
reminderTextField.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
      if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
          .minutesStep(1)
          .setDayFormatter(formatter)
          .mainColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
          .titleTextColor(Color.BLACK)
          .displayListener(new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.DisplayListener() {
              @Override
              public void onDisplayed(SingleDateAndTimePicker picker) {})

            .mustBeOnFuture()
            .title("Set Reminder")
            .listener(new SingleDateAndTimePickerDialog.Listener() {
              @Override
              public void onDateSelected(Date date) {
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
                String reminderTime = formatter.format(date);
                reminderTextField.setText(reminderTime);
              }
            }).display();
          }
```

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaYl7.png)

Comment: You want to split by hour, minute or month and year or both ? Your question and description are not the same unfortunatly it's unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Calendar` Class to do it like :

```
java.util.Date date= new Date("Your date here");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH); // Month
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // Day
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR); // Year
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // Hour
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE); // Minute
```

...

If you want more, you have all the class `Calendar` with the methods on [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Then it's up to you ;)

**Tip** : use `System.out.println()` method to see the results on the console and make sure it's what you want.